# Looking for a nice VPS for $15~30

Tags: vps

I need a nice vps for around 15~30$ monthly. What providers do you recommend?
I found mochahost.com but that provider seems to be bad when looking at the reviews

Comment: -1.... not even the slightest definition waht would make a VPS nice for the poster. Not answerable at this point.

Answer (score 2):

http://linode.com/ might not offer the most for your money (512MB and 16GB disk, 200GB transfer for $20/mo, quad Xeons), but I have found that when it comes to service, they reign superior. They always respond to online tickets the same day, and have an IRC channel for almost instant responses. Some Linode staff are even on ServerFault - https://serverfault.com/users/4724/tasaro for example.

Answer (score 0):

Results of a quick Google search:

http://www.ucvhost.com/
http://www.resellerspanel.com/virtual-private-servers/
http://www.eboundhost.com/hosting/vps/
http://vpslink.com/

However, bear in mind that you're unlikely to find a VPS host that really shines (good support, high availability, acceptable features, consistent performance) for under about $50 a month, and if you're interested in Managed hosting, you'll want to plan on spending at LEAST $60-80 per month.

Comment: I have used a VPS for 600GB BW 8core cpu 2GB RAM 40GB hd for just 15$ a month. And their support were awesome too. It was a Korean company but right now I need some traffic in America